# How to get the indexes of a sort operation instead of a sorted array using numpy?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have a 3D array like so:

```
arr = [[[20, 5, 10], ...], ...]
```

if I do

```
print(arr.argsort())
```

I get the indexes that would sort the array on that last axis:

```
[[[1, 2, 0], ...], ...]
```

But what I want is for each position the index that given element would have, if the array was sorted:

```
[[[2, 0, 1], ...], ...]
```

How can I do this using numpy? I have very large ndarrays so I am trying to avoid things like list comprehensions, etc and just accomplish this directly with numpy instead.

Comment: `np.argsort(np.argsort(arr))` twice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe argsort twice return the inverse index:

```
np.argsort(np.argsort(arr, axis=-1), axis=-1)
```

Output:

```
array([[[2, 0, 1]]])
```

Comment: Thanks! I had this intuition a second ago but could't explain why or if it worked in all cases, so I googled it, and found an explanation here: https://www.berkayantmen.com/rank.html so I'll just leave it as a reference for future readers.